# WPF: binding Bitmap source to XAML resources failure

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I am trying to display a picture loaded by `OpenFileDialog` in a new window.
The first way, which is doing that entirely in code works. I want to do it in another way, though. I attempt to add that image to resources and then use this for a given control.

XAML part:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <Image x:Key="imageResource">
        <Image.Source>
            <BitmapImage UriSource="{Binding ImageUri}" />
        </Image.Source>
    </Image>
</Window.Resources>

<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <Image Name="image"  />
    <Image Name="image2" Grid.Column="1" Source="{Binding imageResource}" />
</Grid>
```

C# code:

```
public partial class PicWindow : Window
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void NotifyPropertyChanged(String propertyName = "")
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
    private Uri imageUri;
    public Uri ImageUri
    {
        get
        {
            return imageUri;
        }
        set
        {
            imageUri = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("ImageUri");
        }
    }

    public PicWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    public PicWindow(string filePath)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        imageUri = new Uri(filePath);
        image.Source = new BitmapImage(imageUri);
    }
}
```

Left column (done in the c# code) displays a loaded picture, but the right one does not (the one with binding usage).
P.S. Regarding that every new picture is opened in a new window I realise that the `ImageUri` change notification is redundant in here. Please ignore this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Drop the Image resource and bind directly to the `ImageUri` property of your Window:

```
<Image Name="image2" Grid.Column="1"
       Source="{Binding ImageUri, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Window}}" />
```

Built-in type conversion will automatically convert from type `Uri` to `ImageSource`.

Comment: I works, but I wondered how do do it by adding my Image to `Window Reference`

Comment: Having an Image element as resource doesn't make sense. You may however declare a BitmapImage as resource.